# Mapping with a condition

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I want to map 2 objects based on a condition, if true mapp else ignore, the condition is not a part of source neither destination

```
  var mapperconfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
               .ForMember(source => source.Titulaires, 
                          opt => opt.Condition(titulaires.HasValue && titulaires == true));
            ....   
        });
```

the extension method Condition() accepts just a type related to source or destination.

Comment: what about if(condition){<Your Code>}?

Comment: thank you for your response but, I used the automapper first, and it maps all the priorities, then if I have to use my codition I have to ignore the map at first and validate it later

Comment: cant you use condtion like this? ` .Condition( condition == true && ?`

Comment: your condition should be relate to source/destination object or attribute, otherwise shouldnt put into auto mapper. this will make logic became mess, can we know what kind condition that you want to put here?

Comment: yes it doesn't work with Condition(), I have 4  boolean conditions, for eachone if true map the specific type else ignore, and the mapperConfiguration at first makes the work of mapping all then when calling the mapper I have all mapped.

Comment: bool? titulaires;                                                                                                
var mapperconfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
               .ForMember(source => source.Titulaires, 
                          opt => opt.Condition(titulaires.HasValue && titulaires == true));
            ....   
        });

Answer (score 1):

AutoMapper allows you to add conditions to properties that must be met before that property will be mapped.

Eg.

```
   public class Foo
{
  public int baz;
}

public class Bar 
{ 
  public uint baz; 
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()       
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Foo,Bar>().ForMember(dest => dest.baz, opt => opt.Condition(src => (src.baz >= 0)));

        var foo1 = new Foo { baz=-1 };      
        var bar1 = Mapper.Map<Bar>(foo1);

        Console.WriteLine("bar1.baz={0}", bar1.baz);

        var foo2 = new Foo{ baz=100 };
        var bar2 = Mapper.Map<Bar>(foo2);


        Console.WriteLine("bar2.baz={0}", bar2.baz);
    }
}
```

Also, they give **Preconditions** functionality

See this link [Conditional Mapping](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conditional-mapping.html)

Comment: hello Tom, thank you for your response, actualy I have a condition that is not a part o source or destination, a conndition to make map on some proprities, for Condition() it can't be use in my case, I have to make " (condition == true) ?mapp(source.prop, destination.prop) : ignore()"

Comment: I try this and what I know that your condition should be related to source/destination object or attribute so try to use if(condition)

Comment: See this examples [example1](https://www.techrepository.in/automapper-conditional-mapping) [example2](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/some-useful-tips-while-using-automapper-in-C-Sharp/)

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your help, I find a way to test my conditions into my automapper configuration : MapperConfiguration mappConf = new MapperConfiguration(config => {
                 config.CreateMap()
             .ForMember(destination => destination.member, option => option.Condition(item => _condition == true))........});